# Undo clicking chrome never save password on the mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, passwords

Sometimes you may want to undo your choice of "Never for this site" when Chrome asks if you want to save a password. But on the mac clicking on the "Show saved passwords" in the Preferences opens the Keychain Access app and you have no way to remove that site from the exceptions list.

This is obviously a bug.

I suppose that deleting all saved passwords will do but I don't want to delete them all. Is there any other workaround? (Chrome 6.0.472.63)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this recipe](http://blog.vicshih.com/2010/04/edit-save-password-exceptions-in-google.html) (low rep = only 1 link per post):

> To remove an entry from the exception list, do the following:
>
> 1. Shut down Chrome
> 2. Probably a good idea to make a backup of the database file
> 3. Open the database file in a SQLite database browser; I use "SQLite Database Browser"
> 4. Select the "Browse Data" tab
> 5. Sites for which "Never for this Site" has been selected will have the value 1 for the column blacklisted_by_user. Double-click the desired cell, change the value to 0, and click "Apply Changes"
> 6. Save and close the database file
> 7. Restart Chrome

For me, the following worked:

```
cd Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
sqlite3 Login\ Data
delete from logins where blacklisted_by_user = 1;
.quit
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. [This being not a regular discussion board](http://superuser.com/about), users with more reputation are able to edit your posts. You can usually put as many URLs in your posts as you need (somewhat obfuscated and non-clickable), and others will then "fix" your post.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of places that might be good to check out:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest
```

(look under AutoFillEnabled)

```
/Users/john/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist
```

In Chrome 8 (dev build), you can undo a "Never save passwords for this site" in the preferences, but I hope that you find a way for Chrome 6!

Comment: no luck, the exceptions are not preferences anyway